# why the following pop function can't work on host or device (cuda)?

Tags: c++, cuda

why the function ***pop()*** of the code can not run with global kernel or using host thread in cuda programming, but other functions are ok? I've been debugging for a long time, but I can't find anything wrong. Can anyone tell why?

```
#define N 10
//define a vector for new or delete dynamically
template<typename T>
class LocalVector
{
private:
    T* m_begin;
    T* m_end;

    size_t capacity;
    size_t length;
    __host__ __device__ void expand() {
        capacity *= 2;
        size_t tempLength = (m_end - m_begin);
        T* tempBegin = new T[capacity];

        memcpy(tempBegin, m_begin, tempLength * sizeof(T));
        delete[] m_begin;
        m_begin = tempBegin;
        m_end = m_begin + tempLength;
        length = static_cast<size_t>(m_end - m_begin);
    }
public:
    __host__ __device__  explicit LocalVector() : length(0), capacity(15) {
        m_begin = new T[capacity];
        m_end = m_begin;
    }
    __host__ __device__ T& operator[] (unsigned int index) {
        return *(m_begin + index);
    }
    __host__ __device__ T* begin() {
        return m_begin;
    }
    __host__ __device__ T* end() {
        return m_end;
    }
    __host__ __device__ ~LocalVector()
    {
        delete[] m_begin;
        m_begin = nullptr;
    }
    __host__ __device__ void add(T t) {
        if ((m_end - m_begin) >= capacity) {
            expand();
        }

        new (m_end) T(t);
        m_end++;
        length++;
    }
    __host__ __device__ T pop() {
        T endElement = (*m_end);
        delete m_end;
        m_end--;
        return endElement;
    }
    __host__ __device__ size_t getSize() {
        return length;
    }
};
//cuda kernel function
__global__ void addKernel(LocalVector<int> *c)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c->pop();
}
//main function
int main() {
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    LocalVector<int> hlv;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        hlv.add(i*2);
    }
    hlv.pop();//can't work，and stop running
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < hlv.getSize(); i++) {
        printf("hlv[%d]=%d,", i,hlv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

You should not `delete` anything when you `pop`, You `delete` only when `expand` or `delete` the entire internal array when destruct. This change will fix:

```
void add(T t) {
    if ((m_end - m_begin) >= capacity) {
        expand();
    }
    *(m_begin + length) = t;
    m_end++;
    length++;
}
 T pop() {
    T endElement = (*m_end);
    m_end--;
    return endElement;
}
 long long  getSize() {
    return length;
}
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8C_7He)

Comment: But what I want to do is to delete the useless element from end array, if that, how to do?

Comment: @yoer you cannot partially delete the internal array, if you want to delete you have to delete all similar to expand, which is waste of time. you just need to keep track of m_end to always have correct result.

Comment: OK. However, I still have a doubt that if the capacity of this array have reached the limit, I don't want to further expand, I just free these useless elements and new a element at these locations, can do that or how?

Comment: @yoer as I said, you have to delete all or nothing. You have to decide for expand in the beginning. you are already tracking m_end correctly, so you won't expand if there is wasted elements in the array. All you need to assure is "don't expand if length < capacity"